# How to find the range of values for the sum of the first n terms in this sequence?

Tags: differential-equations

```
Sum[1/(4^n - 1), {n, 1, n}]
```

What is the value range of the result obtained above?

Comment: You can't use `n` to represent two different things at once. Use `Sum[1/(4^k - 1), {k, 1, n}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon This has no problem or impact. Both results obtained are consistent

Comment: I don’t understand the question

Comment: I also don’t understand your comment to Bob

Comment: It is an elementary mistake to use the same variable name as an iterator (which changes value) and the fixed *limit* of iteration (which does *NOT* change value).  This is true mathematically and especially algorithmically.  Suppose, for instance, you were interested in the particular case $n=10$.  How would any interpreter deal with such an assignment??  "For 10 equals 1 to 10"???  Incidentally, the **proper** sum has value:  $$\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{4}}^{(0)}(n+1)}{\log (4)}-\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{4}}^{(0)}(1)}{\log
   (4)}$$ using the PolyGamma function.

Comment: I think there is a validity to the question. I think OP is asking why Mathematica gave the answer it gave even though the upper limit is same as name of the index. For example `Sum[1/(4^n-1),{n,1,n}]` and `Sum[1/(4^n - 1), {n, 1, m}]` give same special function, (polyGamma) but in one case it uses `n` and in the other case `m`. So I think OP is asking if Mathematica should have complained for the first case when using `{n,1,n}`. At least this is how I understood the question.

Comment: OK... fair enough.  Somehow *Mathematica* "knows" that an $n$ in an iterator is (magically) different from an $n$ as the limit.  I have no idea why the interpreter would do that, think is *SHOULD* be flagged as an error, and don't know why the OP or indeed anyone would ever use that possibly-confusing notation.  Perhaps someone else will try this funny example in C/C++, Python, Matlab, ...  But I don't think this is the core of the OP's true question, which is about "value range" (whatever that is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

sum[n_] = Sum[1/(4^k - 1), {k, 1, n}] // Simplify

(* (-QPolyGamma[0, 1, 1/4] + QPolyGamma[0, 1 + n, 1/4])/Log[4] *)

lim = Limit[sum[n], n -> Infinity]

(* (Log[4/3] - QPolyGamma[0, 1, 1/4])/Log[4] *)
```

The sum is not limited to discrete values:

```
Show[
 Plot[sum[n], {n, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> All],
 DiscretePlot[sum[n], {n, 0, 10}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
    {HoldForm@n, HoldForm@sum}),
 GridLines -> {None, {lim}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashed],
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]